# Highstock setExtremes not working properly

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Actually I'm trying to have a dummy y-Axis which is same as the primary y-Axis but it is opposite from the primary(there is only one series). I'm able to get axis by setting its `min` and `max` using `setExtremes` based on the primary axis, once it is rendered but the limits set are not matching, working fine in jsFiddle.

Did any one face such problem??

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Show some code, or better yet how about a link to that jsFiddle?

Comment: here is what i've tried http://jsfiddle.net/kjsL7/, working fine in fiddle but not on my page

Comment: In case when fiddle works properly, but your website not, how we can reproduce your issue?

Comment: I'll try again updating it to latest version

Comment: Could you just try to use `linkedTo` option? See [ref](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#yAxis.linkedTo).

Comment: Yes I forgot about this option. I'm sure this will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it works

`linkedTo` is the property that worked for me.

Hope thill will help some one or other